# Alerts Changed via Powershell do not show updates in SubEdit.aspx

Tags: powershell, alert

I'm having a weird issue when trying to update user alerts via Powershell. I am able to update the alerts, and getting properties on the alerts as well as practical testing shows that the alert properties have changed (specifically, changing the eventtype from Add to Modify).

However, if you look at the settings in SubEdit.aspx (Alert Me > Manage My Alerts), it still shows the old Change Type ("New items are added" instead of "Existing items are modified"). If you update the alert via this page, then look at the properties via Powershell, it is changed. You can then change it again in Powershell, confirm that you have changed it through properties and testing, but SubEdit.aspx still shows the old setting.

Wondering if anyone has ever seen this/has any idea what is causing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to clear the browser cache? clear the cache, close the browser and reopen it.

Comment: Yes. In fact I even opened it on a different computer that I had not viewed on it yet, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the .Properties["eventtypeindex"] when you set the .EventType.  Example:
$alertItem.EventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventType]::Add; 
$alertItem.Properties["eventtypeindex"] = 1;
$alertItem.Update();